# Different themes for different classes in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, themes, customization

I have spent literally hours looking for a question even like this and have failed to find anything so please help me.

I want to be able to have different themes for different classes in eclipse. This may seem vague so let me give an example.
In my normal Java code I love the MoonRise theme where my background and everything is dark and my code is light; it is easier on my eyes. However I just started using OpenGl 3.2 GLSL in my code and noticed that the default font is so dark and hard to see!

After a lot of searching the closest thing I could find is changing the text colors of specific things in GLSL. Which is nice! However, me being a very color oriented person I would love if all .glsl files or .fsh .vsh etc could be in a different theme. Example: .java is MoonRise while .glsl is classic (white background).

If you know of anything like this or any way to do this please help me out because I feel as if I have looked everywhere!

**Update I have searched a combined of 5 hours this week without a single hint of how do accomplish this